# loop that adds the number 5 to all values of a vector that are smaller than 4

Tags: python

Im trying to add 5 to this vector if a number in the vector is less then 4. I feel like im pretty close but it isnt running correctly. Can anyone give me some help adding 5 to any value less then 4 in the vector?

```
from pylab import * 
numberlist = [3.2,6,7.8,1,3,2.5]
def x(numberlist):
    for num in numberlist:
        if num > 4:
            print(num)
        else :
            print(num + 5)
print x([3.2,6,7.8,1,3,2.5])
```

Comment: This looks like it does something. What is the difference between what it does and what you want it to do?

Comment: I removed the [tag:R] tag since the question didn't seem to have anything to do with R (though some R related answers were submitted before that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have does exactly what you're describing.  Looks like you're new to python, possibly new to programming in general.

The code is a bit confusing for the following reasons.

1. You define a global variable named `numberlist` and assign it an array of numbers.
2. The parameter for you function `x` is named `numberlist` again.
3. When calling `x`, you pass an array of the same values you assigned to the global variable `numberlist` in the beginning.

Important points to note:

- The global variable `numberlist` and `x`'s parameter named `numberlist` are two TOTALLY DIFFERENT VARIABLES.  The effect you have is that the global variable `numberlist` isn't accessible inside of your function `x`. You're not actually using the global variable `numberlist` anywhere.
- If you wanted to use the global variable `numberlist` and pass it to `x`, instead of `x([3.2,6,7.8,1,3,2.5])`, you would just do `x(numberlist)`.
- You should rename `x`'s `numberlist` parameter to something else.  `mylist` for example.
- You really don't need the import statement at the top.

Taking those into account, your code is more readable as follows:

```
def x(mylist):
    for num in mylist:
        if num > 4:
            print(num)
        else :
            print(num + 5)
numberlist = [3.2,6,7.8,1,3,2.5]
print x(numberlist)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, and yes I am very new to python and programming in general. This makes a lot more sense to me though. I am still getting syntax errors towards then end of the program though.                  Name error: name x is not defined?

Comment: Copy/pasting this into a text file, saving it, then running it from the command line like `python test.py` works for me.  Not sure what to tell you.  How exactly are you executing the script?

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
x = [ v + 5 if v < 4 else v for v in x ]
```

?

Comment: Sorry,this is how I put it in. Im kind of confused now.                                                               v = array[3.2,6,7.8,1,3,2.5]
x = [ v + 5 if v < 4 else v for v in x ] 
print [x]

Comment: @Bill -- the array should be x, not v.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding what PyLab is correctly, then you should have a numpy array available and should be avoiding for loops and using array manipulations...

```
from pylab import * # which should bring numpy ndarray into scope!?
a = ndarray( [3.2,6,7.8,1,3,2.5] )
a[a < 4] += 5.
print a
# [ 8.2  6.   7.8  6.   8.   7.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with the python side but on the R side this is trivial

```
x <- sample(1:10, 20, rep = T)
> x
 [1]  5  9  1  1  8  9  5 10  2  3  8  1  5  9  7  1  6  2 10  6
 > x[which(x<5)] <- x[which(x<5)] + 5
Arrrr> x
 [1]  5  9  6  6  8  9  5 10  7  8  8  6  5  9  7  6  6  7 10  6
```

Comment: You beat me to it, but then OP beat us both by removing the R tag. Although I think he wants to add 5 to each element that's less than 4.

Comment: That replaces values less than or equal to 5 with 4, not adds 5 to values less than 4.

Comment: Sorry, Brian. itchy trigger finger and all. I fixed it.